# Force Extjs grid to recalculate width - after hiding a simple "div" next to it

Tags: layout, extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a grid in ExtJS and a div that I place or toggle to the left of it. This div is not managed by ExtJS.

When I show this div, the grid slips to the right and this div shows up on its left.
The problem I have is that when I hide the div, the grid squeezes and looses the full width it  had based on the "fit" layout meaning there is some empty space left on the right of it now.

Now, as soon as I resize the window, it catches the event and resizes itself but not before it.

Anyone with any suggestions I could try in order to maintain the grid's stretch, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly calling `doLayout()` on the grid or the grid's parent, when the div is hidden.